# Setting up VPN connection to SonicWall in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to my company computer, which is behind a SonicWall. The only "solutions" I found were several years old, mostly using OpenSwan (which has been replaced by StrongSwan, as far as I know), and none of them has been working (I have no clue about network settings and just tried some copy-paste stuff). I tried using [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1583143) and [that](http://koo.fi/blog/2015/04/04/vpn-between-strongswan-and-sonicwall/), but could not transfer them to my problem.

So this is what I did so far:

- installed `strongswan`
- set up the SonicWall settings I found that should work (see image below)
- tried to set up `/etc/ipsec.conf` and `/etc/ipsec.secrets` and failed

I have the following information:

- Gateway: My.Gate.Way.IP
- IP of computer I want to connect to: Remote.Desktop.Computer.IP
- Shared secret: MY%SHARED%SECRET
- SonicWall unique identifier: 123456789
- User name and password, registered in the SonicWall

Can someone show me a configuration file that might work for my environment? 
I tried this as `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file
# basic configuration
config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no
# Add connections here.
conn sonciwall
    # Own IP
    left=MY.IP.IN.WLAN
    leftsubnet=MY.IP.IN.0/24
    leftid=@GroupVPN
    # Gateway
    right=MY.GATE.WAY.IP
    rigthsubnet=MY.GATE.WAY.0/24
    # SonicWall unique identifier
    rightid=@123456789
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=3des-sha1!
    auto=start
    aggrmode=yes
```

And for `/etc/ipsec.secrets`:

```
@GroupVPN @123456789 : PSK "MY%SHARED%SECRET"
# Following line was added by NetworkManager-l2tp
include /etc/ipsec.d/*.secrets
```

And after setting up things correctly, how can I then connect to my company computer as it would be possible with `Remote Desktop` on a Windows machine?

[image]

Please let me know in case I missed some important information, I will then try to add it.

---

Took me some time, but I finally tried the wonderful answer from @Douglas Kosovic. Unfortunately, the connection still won't set up. Installation worked fine, but I fear I miss something in the configuration.
Here is my setup from the GUI:

[image] [image]

For ipsec.conf and ipsec.secrets, see above.

---

In the end, it turned out to be most likely a setting in the firewall. I then used [netExtender](https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/cgi-bin/welcome) by SonicWall to then make the connection work and now  use [Remmina](https://remmina.org/) as my remote desktop client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following page, Diffie Hellman Group 2 is modp1024 :

- https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv1CipherSuites

So the `ike` (phase 1) and `esp`  (phase 2) lines should be :

```
ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
esp=3des-sha1!
```

You might find it easier to use the network-manager-l2tp VPN GUI client which uses strongswan and xl2tpd to do L2TP/IPsec connections. Unfortunately the version of network-manager-l2tp in the Ubuntu repository won't support the `@123456789` Gateway ID, so will need to build from source.

**To build from source:**

Prerequisites packages (note : you can safely copy and paste the `\` shell line continuation character) :

```
sudo apt install \
build-essential \
git \
intltool \
libtool \
network-manager-dev \
libnm-util-dev \
libnm-glib-dev \
libnm-glib-vpn-dev \
libnm-gtk-dev \
libnm-dev \
libnma-dev \
ppp-dev \
libdbus-glib-1-dev \
libsecret-1-dev \
libgtk-3-dev \
libglib2.0-dev \
xl2tpd \
strongswan
```

Obtain the source code :

```
git clone https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp.git
cd network-manager-l2tp
git checkout nm-1-2
```

Configure :

```
./autogen.sh
./configure \
  --disable-static --prefix=/usr \
  --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
  --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager \
  --localstatedir=/var \
  --with-pppd-plugin-dir=/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7
```

Building and installation:

```
make
sudo make install
```

You will need to logout of your desktop environment (or reboot) for gnome-shell to properly pickup the installed plugin.

In the nework-manager-l2tp IPsec Options dialog box, enable IPsec and use the following options:

- Gateway ID : @123456789
- Phase 1 Algorithms : 3des-sha1-modp1024!
- Phase 2 Algorithms : 3des-sha1!

the other options should be fairly obvious.

If you do use network-manager-l2tp, you might need to stop the system xl2tpd service, see "*Issue with not stopping system xl2tpd service*" :

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/tree/nm-1-2

Comment: But if you have setup SonicWall only for IKEv2 and not IKEv1, you should use network-manager-strongswan which only supports IPsec IKEv2. If you have setup the SonicWall for L2TP/IPsec IKEv1 then use network-manager-l2tp

Comment: Wow, that's a detailed answer, thanks a lot! Can only try in two weeks when back in the office, but I'll definitely report back.

Comment: Well, after a long time of not doing anything on this, it finally worked: with a totally different approach. I think, in the end it was a missing setting in the firewall, because in principal, it seemed to work. So thanks again, I'll try to mark the question as resolved.